# In my CSS, I'm getting a Parse error towards the bottom of the code I have presented starting with "h1 {font-size: 2em;...}"

Tags: html, css, parsing

The code that starts with `"h1 {font-size: 2em; padding-top: 0.25em; padding-left: 1.5em; width: 85%; text-align: center;}"` which is towards the end of the code provides the parse problem. I'm not sure why this is.

```
body {background-color: #3F2860; color:#3F2860; font-family: Arial; }
header {background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg); background-color: #9BC1C2; 
 background-position: right; background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 150px; width: 1600px; padding-right:1em; padding-left: 1em;
 /*text-align: center;*/}
h1 {padding-top:50px; padding-left:2em}
nav {float: left; width: 160px; font-weight: bold; 
padding:1em; border: 3px #CCCCCC;}
nav a {text-decoration: none; display: block; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;
 border: 3px outset #CCCCCC; padding: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; }
nav ul { padding-left: 0; list-style: none;}
nav a {text-decoration: none;}
nav a:link { color: #3F2860; }
nav a:visited { color: #497777; }
nav a:hover { color: #A26100; border: 3px inset #333333}
main {padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em; margin-left: 170px;
 padding-top: 1em}
footer {background-color: #9BC1C2; font-size: 0.60em;
 text-align: center; font-style: italic; padding:1em}
#wrapper {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 80%; 
background-color:#F5F5F5; min-width:1200px; max-width:1480px;}
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.floatleft {float: left; margin-right: 4em}
.clear {clear: both;}
header, nav, main, footer { display: block; }
#mobile { display: none;}
#desktop { display: inline;}
/*big screen 1024 pixel screen*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){}
body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#wrapper { width: 100%; min-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
header {padding-top: 1px; }
nav {float: none; width: auto; padding-left: 2em; }
nav a {padding: 0.2em; margin-left: 0.3em; float: left; width: 23%}
main {padding-top: 2.5em; padding-bottom: 2.5em; padding-left: 1em;
 padding-right:1em; margin: 0; font-size: 90%; clear: both; }
#hero img {width: 100%; height: auto; }
h2, h3, p, dl { padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em }
main ul {margin-left: 2em; }
 .floatleft {margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: 1em; }
 .clear {padding-left: 2em; }
 @media only all and (max-width: 768px)
h1 {font-size: 2em; padding-top: 0.25em; padding-left: 1.5em;
 width: 85%; text-align: center;}
nav a {padding: 0.5em; width: 45%; float: left; min-width: 6em;
 margin-left: 0.5em; }
main {padding-top: 0; }
.floatleft {float: none; display: none; }
#hero {display: none; }
 footer {padding: 0.5em; margin: 0; }
#mobile { display: inline; }
#desktop { display: none; }
```

Comment: https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css

Answer (score 0):

Your code was missing curly brackets after the media query to contain the `h1` code.
Here is the modified code:

```
@media only all and (max-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
        padding-top: 0.25em;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        width: 85%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

You could also just copy the entire thing:

```
body {
    background-color: #3F2860;
    color: #3F2860;
    font-family: Arial;
}

header {
    background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
    background-color: #9BC1C2;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    width: 1600px;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    /*text-align: center;*/
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 2em
}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 3px #CCCCCC;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:link {
    color: #3F2860;
}

nav a:visited {
    color: #497777;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #A26100;
    border: 3px inset #333333
}

main {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    margin-left: 170px;
    padding-top: 1em
}

footer {
    background-color: #9BC1C2;
    font-size: 0.60em;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 1em
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    min-width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1480px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.floatleft {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4em
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

header, nav, main, footer {
    display: block;
}

#mobile {
    display: none;
}

#desktop {
    display: inline;
}

/*big screen 1024 pixel screen*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    padding-top: 1px;
}

nav {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 2em;
}

nav a {
    padding: 0.2em;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    float: left;
    width: 23%
}

main {
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    padding-bottom: 2.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
    clear: both;
}

#hero img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

h2, h3, p, dl {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em
}

main ul {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

.floatleft {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.clear {
    padding-left: 2em;
}

@media only all and (max-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
        padding-top: 0.25em;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        width: 85%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

nav a {
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    min-width: 6em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}

main {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.floatleft {
    float: none;
    display: none;
}

#hero {
    display: none;
}

footer {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
}

#mobile {
    display: inline;
}

#desktop {
    display: none;
}
```